# bcc: ImportError cannot import name BPF

Tags: bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I am getting the following error when trying run the example `hello_world.py`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/bcc/examples/hello_world.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bcc import BPF
ImportError: cannot import name BPF
```

I installed bcc from source ([link](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md#ubuntu---source)).
I also installed both the python bcc bindings packages, `python-bcc` and `python3-bcc` but no luck.

I am running Ubuntu **18.04** and kernel version **4.15.0-117-generic**.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Related issue](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2278)

Comment: Does it work if you install the bcc packages? (`sudo apt-get install bpfcc-tools linux-headers-$(uname -r)`)

Comment: Did you try running the hello_world with both Python2 and Python3?

Comment: @pchaigno It doesn't work even after installing the `bcc` packages. Tried with both python2 and python3, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. I was using the `pyenv` to manage my python versions, so the python was looking files in the wrong locations.

```
$ python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages())'
['/home/sagar/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

I tried with a `python3` command, which was not installed by `pyenv` and I don't get the above error.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 20.04, I execute the following command to fix it.

```
sudo apt-get install bpfcc-tools linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```